# My postgreSql database connecton error problem

Tags: database, postgresql

**Hi everyone not working my postgre database fatal error, sorry many clients already What is the problem ?**

```
  Error code --->
  SEVERITY_LOCALIZED=FATAL, SEVERITY_NON_LOCALIZED=FATAL, CODE=53300, MESSAGE=sorry, 
  too many clients already
```

Answer (score 1):

[Error](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html) 53300 is thrown if the number of database connections exceeds any of:

- the difference between the database parameters `max_connections - supreuser_reserved_connections`
- the connection limit for the database user, if set
- the connection limit for the database, if set

But I guess you want to know what to do to avoid the error. The answer is:

- debug and fix the connection leak in your application
- use a connection pool with a conservatively set upper limit

Comment: My PostgreSql max connection not working here is read-only

Comment: I don't understand that comment.

Comment: I know how to change the max connection I want to change but it doesn't change?

Comment: How can I change the max connection?

Comment: You don't change `max_connections`. You reduce the number of client connections, ideally with a connection pool.

Comment: Please write query example

Comment: where and how I decreased client connection?

Comment: In your connection pool. Also, as I said, make sure you return connections to the pool after use.